# como crear en angular un modelo con arrays y usarlo en un componente

Tags: angular, model

como crear un angular un modelo con arrays y usarlo en un componente?
Estoy usando esta API https://rawg.io/apidocs la cual tiene un objecto Game con muchas propiedades pero yo solo necesito usar algunas entre ellas propiedades que contienen varios valores.

el modelo debe de quedar asi?

```
export class Game{
  id: any;
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public image: string,
    public releaseOn: Array<ReleaseOn>,// do it an array of releaseOn platform
    public releaseDate: string,
    public genre: Array<Genres>,// do it an array of genres
    public rating: number,
  ){}
}

export class Genres {
  constructor(
  genre: string
  ){
    
  }
}

export class ReleaseOn {
  constructor(
    releaseOn: string
  )
  {}

}
```

releaseOn y Genre son arrays, en el codigo anterior del modelo he creado una clase para cada propiedad que es un array luego en el constructor de mi componente utilizo

```
   this.games = new Game('', '', [],  '', [], 1 );
    console.log(this.games);// pero el console.log dice que el objecto Game está vacio.

    Game {name: "", image: "", releaseOn: Array(0), releaseDate: "", genre: Array(0), …}
    genre: []
    image: ""
    name: ""
    rating: 1
    releaseDate: ""
    releaseOn: []
    __proto__: Object


pero los objectos se muestran en pantalla el modelo no lo estoy usando pero consigo mostrar los objetos. 

games.component.html

    <div class="card-columns">
        <app-game-card [games]="game" *ngFor="let game of games"></app-game-card>
    </div>

games.component.ts

    constructor(
        private gamesService:GamesService,
        private router: Router,
      ) 
      {
        this.games = new Game('', '', [],  '', [], 1 );
        console.log(this.games);
        
    
      }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gamesService.getListGames().subscribe( (data: any) =>{
      //console.log(data.results);
      console.log(data);
      this.games = data.results;
      //this.count = data.results.length;
      console.log(this.count);
      //this.nextpage = game.next;
      console.log(this.nextpage);
      console.log(data.results);
      console.log(data.results[0].platforms[0]);
      data.results.forEach((game) => {
        //Looping Platform for each game
        game.platforms.forEach((platform)=> { 
                //your code here
                console.log(platform);
            });
    });

  });
  }
```

game-card.component.ts

```
export class GameCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() games: any = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }



}
```

mi duda basicamente es saber como implementar modelos con arrays en angular y en este caso tener información en el objecto "Game"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes inicializar el arreglo de esta manera:

```js
export class Game{
  id: any;
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public image: string,
    public releaseOn: ReleaseOn[]=[],
    public releaseDate: string,
    public genre: Genres[]=[],
    public rating: number,
  ){}
}
```

Así, no tendrás problemas a la hora de estar validando los arreglos o iterando sobre ellos.

Y en tu component, para que tengas ayuda del editor puedes usar:

```
@Input() games: Game[]= [];
```

Answer (score 0):

El tipado lo haces mediante Interfaces, ya que estas trabajando con Angular y TS y en internet hay una página llamada [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) que te ayudar a tipar tus valores, puede copiar ahí tu JSON, y a la derecha seleccionar en lenguaje Typescript, con esta configuración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, tu clase transformada a interface debe quedar masomenos así

```
export interface Game {
    id:          string;
    name:        string;
    image:       string;
    releaseOn:   string[];
    releaseDate: string;
    genre:       string[];
    rating:      string;
}
//releaseOn y releaseDate en este caso son un arreglo de string, si en caso es un arreglo de objetos, también deberas tiparlos mediante una interface;
```

Ahora tu código deberia quedar así

```
//Si recibes un solo objeto game
games:Game;
//Si recibes un array de objetos game
games:Game[];

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.gamesService.getListGames().subscribe( (data: any) =>{

      this.games = data.results;
      
    });
}
```